# Secondary site on MSM not retaining its URL

Tags: multi-site-manager, config

EE 2.7.2.

I have a secondary site on Multi Site Manager. Users can only login to EE from the main site, so I have no admin.php for the secondary site.

In the secondary site's index.php, I have:

```
 $assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'secondary_site_name';
 $assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://primarysite.com/cp';
 $assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://secondarysite.com';
```

However, when I go to Admin --> General Configuration for the secondary site, **URL to the root directory of your site** is still set to primarysite.com

How do I make this setting correct? Note: I will be adding additional sites later.

Answer (score 1):

EE CP don't use variables from index.php. Only from config's or from admin.php. Index.php is only effected on Frontend.

For other sites the system preference is keep in DB (exp_sites table). So you just need to change it for each site.

p.s. possible you setup your first site site_url in admin.php - you need to removed for your model.

Comment: To clarify - the CP is only accessible by logging in at the primary domain: domain.com/cp

So there isn't an admin.php for each site.

When I try to save different settings in system prefs (from the CP), they are overridden by my config.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest, what problems exactly does this cause? I'm currently in the process of setting up an MSM build (actually upgrading it from an old EE1 installation) and your question made me notice that I have this happening too.

Are you using a config bootstrap (FocusLab Master Config)? If so you can 'fix' it by adding this to your config.master.php:

```
// --------------------------------------------
// RESET MSM SETTINGS IN A SHARED CONTROL PANEL
// --------------------------------------------

// are we in the control panel?
if (isset($_GET['D']) && $_GET['D'] == 'cp')
{
    switch ($_REQUEST['exp_cp_last_site_id']) {
        case '1' : $env_config['site_url'] = "http://site1.com/"; break;
        case '3' : $env_config['site_url'] = "http://site3.com/"; break;
        case '5' : $env_config['site_url'] = "http://site5.com/"; break;
    }
}
```

If you're not using a bootstrap, this should work in your main config.php file too, but change the `$env_config` to just `$config` instead. In each case you'll need to hardcode the site id and the site url.

Comment: I tried this, but changing the site_url now affects how add-ons like Wyvern access their supporting files. Primarily, I just wanted to get LiveLook to accept the right URL.

Comment: I would use symlinks if possible to point the secondary sites' theme folders at that of the main site.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the best solution here. Is there another option?

Comment: What problems does your original question cause?

Comment: The way I have settings now, everything works in the CP except Live Look (as far as I can tell). For example, when I'm working on site #2, my Wyvern and Assets fields all work properly. When I view source, I can see that Wyvern js and css files are loading from site1.com/path/to/files which is what I want.  I supposed fixing LiveLook is the main concern right now.

Comment: So you're saying my solution fixes Live Look but breaks Wyvern and Assets? If so, try adding the theme path variables (`$config['theme_folder_path']` and `$config['theme_folder_url']`) into the switch statement and setting them explicitly to site1. Are you using FocusLab Master Config?

Comment: To clarify - I'd rather not use symlinks. I'm not the host allows them, and I try to avoid solutions like this for ease of maintenance. I'm not using FocusLab Master Config, it seemed to heavyweight for the job.